# What is the best practice in regards of the Nginx/apache default site? Remove or leave?

Tags: nginx, apache2

I was wondering what is the best practice in handling the default site configuration the webservers are shipped? What are the advantages/disadvantages of removing the default sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sites are there mainly to validate that your web server is up and running and that it is reachable. Using the default website you can test whether or not your web server is reachable from LAN, Internet, etc...

It is common practice to remove it once you've built your actual website. It is not a major security fault to leave it running, but in the IT world, it's better to have the least amount of public facing services.

There are no real big advantages or disadvantages of leaving them running. One advantage is that if your website dies, you can confirm whether your web service is still running properly by visiting the default page, and as I mentionned earlier, it allows you to test connectivity.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer Dexirian! That gives enough insight.